# Does CORS work in IE 11 using SSL xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

In IE 11 I have the following problem:  I can't seem to make a CORS XMLHttpRequest from an SSL page to another SSL url on a different domain.  It works in FF and Chrome.  I cannot use XDomainRequest (deprecated), and I can't use jQuery or other libraries, must be javascript.

```
function test_Alert(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = "action=something";
    var xUrl= "https://some-domain.com?auth=123456&otherval=abcd");
    request.open('POST', xUrl, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {if (request.readyState==4) alert("It worked!");};
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    request.send(params);
}
```

[image]

CORS is configured on the remote server, and it is working.

I CANNOT ask the clients to modify their client browsers settings.

I am able to do XMLHttpRequest calls to the local server using url="/dir/..." with no domain

Is there something I am missing or are SSL to SSL CORS requests in IE 11 not allowed or functioning?  I believe I will be required to use the server as a proxy to call the url for this request which will be slow, but probably necessary if I can't resolve.

Even confirmation that what I am trying to do is not possible, or better yet an example of what I need to do to make it work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is IE11 running as IE11?

Comment: If you mean, am I running in compatability mode, no, I'm not.  Emulation mode is set to default.

Comment: Thanks, epascarello, this helped me find the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I ran a bunch of tests from different servers and the end result is that, yes, CORS works in SSL to SSL connections.  The reason I was receiving the above error is because of the platform I am using for development.  It includes a meta-tag in the html header of every page that runs emulation for IE

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

I can't remove the tag so I will see if there is a way to override.